# how I convert a classNames to an icon element in angular use pipe

Tags: angular, icons, pipe

I want to convert  class names  to an icon.
eg: 
the input class names are "anticon anticon-tags"
I want to get the icon like this `"<i class="anticon anticon-tags"></i>"`
the pipe I write like that, I can only get the first class name. How can I set all class name to the element class.

```
transform(iconClass: string):any {
   return `<i class=${iconClass}></i>`
}
```

Comment: I can only get the element like this  <i class="anticon"></i>

Comment: can you add stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any pipe that return html has to pass the value to `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

*font awesome pipe*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'fa'
})
export class FaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private dom: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(className: string): any {
    return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<i class="fa fa-${className}"></i>`);
  }

}
```

*template*

```
{{ 'fa-plus' | fa}} // this is invalid you have to use proprty binding 

<span [innerHTML]="'plus'|fa"></span>
```

Comment: return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<i class="${className}"></i>`);   I change your code and solve my problem. Thanks very much

Comment: @zhenpeng happy to help